# Should an open bounded set have finite subcover. Shouldn't boundedness be the only criteria for having finite subcover?

Tags: real-analysis

I am learning bit of real analysis, and have encountered hiene borel theorem. But shouldn't boundedness be the only criteria for finite subcover instead of compactness. Apostol defines boundedness as for every element of the set there exists a ball which contains the set. So this ball will cover the set.

Comment: This is a bit unclear.  You seem to be confusing compactness with boundedness:  one says something about ALL possible covers, the other says something about a single open set.  Big difference.  Being bounded alone is NOT enough to get the theorems you need in analysis/topology.

Comment: Okay, got it. I was not confusing compactness with boundedness, but was thinking there obviously exist a finite subcover for a bounded set. But okay it is not true for all the covers. Thanks!

Comment: Correct.  This is why closedness matters in the Heine-Borel theorem: having a fuzzy boundary allows you to concoct "bad" open covers like the one in the answer below.  Closedness prevents this (as long as you're also bounded).

Comment: Even if this was the correct definition of compactness it would still have nothing to do with boundedness. Any subset of a topological space would be compact since it is covered by the space itself, which is open.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the interval $(-1,1)$. Define a covering set $C=\{(-a,a)\mid 0<a<1\}$. Then no finite subset of $C$ covers $(-1,1)$.